# Transforming EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326

Tags: gdal, google-maps, coordinate-system

I am new to gdal and have a simple question. I want to transform an image from OpenStreetMap projection to Nasa Blue Marble projection. What I understand is that OpenStreetMap projection is EPSG:3857 and Blue Marble projection is EPSG:4326 (http://www.paulillsley.com/gia/index.html).

So, I simply downloaded a sample 256*256 tile like this: http://a.tah.openstreetmap.org/Tiles/tile/0/0/0.png and applied the following command:

gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:4326 "0.png" "o_bluemarble.png"

I received the following error:
"Copying color table from 0.png to new file.
ERROR 1: Unable to compute a transformation between pixel/line
and georeferenced coordinates for 0.png.
There is no affine transformation and no GCPs."

From where should I start?

**Update 1**

I got it. I need to define the bounds. Firstly, I got the bounds:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857
-180 85.05
-20037508.3427892 20036051.9193368 0
```

I used 85.05 as it is the approximation to infinity in Spherical Mercator used by Bing. Then, I used the following commands:

```
./gdal_translate -of Gtiff -co "tfw=yes"  -a_ullr -20037508.3427892 20036051.9193368 20037508.3427892 -20036051.9193368 -a_srs "EPSG:3857"  "input.png" "input_tfw.tiff"

./gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -ts 256 128 "input_tfw.tiff" "output.tif"
```

The problem now is that by comparing an image downloaded from openstreetmap with Blue Marble, the poles are not aligned properly. I mean here Greenland, not the far pole. What do think the problem is?

Comment: 85,05° N is not really Google's approximation for infinity. It is just chosen to get a square tile for zoom level 0. It is true that 90°N will be infinity in that projection, but everything between 85 and 89.99 can be projected, though rather distorted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what your problem is. The image I get from OSM looks like this:

[image: OSM topmost tile]

And after running your commands I get this:

[image: WGS84 image]

Which looks like how I would expect a lon/lat dataset to look, which is essentially an [equirectangular projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection):

[image]

Comment: There was a slight shift near poles but I fixed it by providing a more accurate lat value (85.0511). Thanks.