# Converting lat/long to EPSG:3857 coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, web-mercator

The map widget I'm using gives me click locations in lat/long.  I need to convert those coordinates to EPSG:3857 to query a database.

Most of the solutions I've found use the formula described in this gist: [convert from long/lat to google mercator (or EPSG:4326 to EPSG:900913)](https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/871897) .  But I'm in doubt about the constant `90` used in the `y` calculation:

```
var y = Math.log(Math.tan((90 + lat) * Math.PI / 360)) / (Math.PI / 180);
```

The [formula described on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Mercator#Formulas) seems to suggest that instead of `90`, I should use `85.051129`.  I've found other references to that value in questions such as [Transforming EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/transforming-epsg3857-to-epsg4326).

Which is correct, and why?

Comment: The gist is using feet, plus yeah, I haven't seen those values. John Snyder gives y = R*ln(tan(PI/4.0 + phi/2)) with  phi in radians.

Comment: @mkennedy Where do you get that the gist is using feet?  The function is called `degrees2meters`, and the magic number `20037508.34` is half the Earth's circumference at the equator in meters.

Comment: Oops, my mistake. Radius of wgs84/grs80 is 20.9 million feet. I saw the 20 million and jumped to the wrong conclusion.